# Tevilas Keilim in Man-made lake

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

Forgive me in advance if this is a duplicate- I saw some similar questions, but none that seemed to address this in particular: Can a man-made lake be used for Tevilas Keilim? I live in an area where the Mikvah has limited hours. There are several man-made lakes nearby, the largest of which is 24.8 acres.  I have no idea how the lakes were originally built.

Comment: This is like asking if a man made structure can be used as a sukkah. Some can and some can't.

Comment: https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/a-recent-halacha-yomis-linked-below-cited-rav-belsky-ztls-ruling-that-that-one-may-immerse-a-utensil-in-a-lake-provided-it-has-not-rained-in-the-last-few-days-can-you-please-cl/#:~:text=Furthermore%2C%20Rabbi%20Belsky%20advised%20that,immersed%20at%20a%20deeper%20point.

Comment: You should discuss this with your local rabbi. It will likely depend on whether water is flowing in and out of the lake, whether the lake is fed by natural water (e.g., springs) or the utility, and maybe other factors. I don't think the fact the lake is man-made is that relevant

Comment: That sounds OK. I think the *poskim* discuss if a pool of water cess is a *kosher mikvah*.